# RestCall Transaction issue for Rollback Scenarios

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am using Spring Boot and not much experience on Transactions stuff...

```
@Service
@Transactional
class FundTransferService {
    public void doSomeFunds(){

        if(realPaymentGateway()){
            //then do db call, to update User Transaction details, WHAT IF SERVER GOES DOWN HERE OR ANY EXCEPTION??
        }

    }

    public boolean realPaymentGateway(){
        //Using Braintree to transfer Funds
    }
}
```

Above there are 2 things happening, **paymentGateway**(which is some rest call) and if success, then only **updating DB** with User Transaction details.

I want above 2 THINGS should happen Atomic, **I mean either both (Rest and DB) shud Success, or rollback everything..**

**My problem is:**

**Q1)** While Updating DB details, due to some exception or server goes down, then might rollback happen only for DB stuff, but not RESTCALL..

**Q2)** Should I first update DB and then go for PaymentGateway for transfering funds or reverse should be correct? Please suggest me..

Hope you understand my query, so whats the solution for above problem?

Comment: So, there is really no way to stop? then how big sites like Amazon, Ebay or other ecommerce sites.. are doing then?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot atomically do what you want to do, like span a distributed transaction, because `Braintree` is a REST service outside of your control.

You can however, call Braintree, and afterwards update your database accordingly. This way, there's a minimal time-window right between your brain-tree call and your transaction commit, that your server gets unexpectedly "killed", but there's no easy way around that in the scope of this answer.

You could also have some sort of write-ahead-log, where you try and remember what REST service you are going to call and then reconcile with the actual REST calls that happened, but this is a bit more elaborate and quite possibly overkill.

Comment: So, there is really no way to stop? then how big sites like Amazon, Ebay etc.. are doing then?

Comment: there is no easy answer to your question. it depends entirely on the workflow and on what technologies you have access to, like distributed transactions/XA. etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply transactions only for transactional resources. As I understood you have 1 non-transactional input (further, TX) (call with payment request) and 2 outputs (non-TX remote REST call and TX SQL database). If you want to keep real-time consistency, I can propose the next architectural approach:
- put payment request into message queue. MQ Broker must support XA protocol for 2PC commit (for instance, ActiveMQ);
- your service reads message from queue using XA-connection, sends REST request to remote server and saves data into DB (which also supports XA protocol) using XA-connection;
- if REST call will failed or something else, you will rollback changes and start from processing payment request from the queue again. BTW, your remote REST resource must be idempotent;

If you're using non-transactional resoureces no way to keep it in consistent .
Also, you can lookup information, for instance, on Atomikos site for using 2PC.